# Calculus: Visualizing the bounded region to solve volume

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid that results when the region bounded by $x=1-y^2$ and the y-axis is revolved around the y-axis.

What does this region look like?

How can you bind the region around the y-axis? What does that mean? I believe this is an infinitely large region but how am I wrong?

Comment: In which direction does the parabola $x=1-y^2$ open?

Comment: I'm not sure. I rewrote the problem in terms of x and graphed it that way and calculated unsuccessfully. If I think about it in terms of y, I'm not sure how to re-orient my graph to write my integral.

Comment: The parabola opens in the negative $x$ direction.  So, the $y$ axis forms a "left" bound for the region, and the parabola is the right bound.

Comment: How do you know the parabola isn't left bound? Are you looking from left to right starting from where you see the parabola opens up and ending at the y-axis limit and final bound?

Comment: It may help to interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$. So we are looking at the region bounded by $y=1-x^2$ and the $x$-axis, and rotating about the $x$-axis. You probably know what $y=1-x^2$ looks like.

Comment: @Jeffrey The only *finite* area that is bounded by those two curves has the parabola as a right bound.  The other areas are infinite.